# concurrentConsumers in camel route to share the same threadPool

Tags: apache-camel

Consired I'm having the following routes:

```
from('activemq:queue:myQueue?concurrentConsumers=10').
.....

from('seda:mySedaQueue?concurrentConsumers=10').
.....
```

How to make them sharing the same `threadPool`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible as when you use concurrentConsumers with SEDA they have a private thread pool with a fixed size you specify, eg in your case its 10. Then all 10 threads is active and polling for new messages to process.

This is by design, as sharing a thread pool does not make sense / gives any benefit. As thread is not returned back in the pool, as the threads is always active.

Comment: See it. Good answer. Anyway, I need to have two seda: queues and multiple threads consuming from them. I need them to share the same thread pool. I've found that this construct is not good `from("seda:queue").threads(10)...` as they "Can wind up with two BlockQueues: one from the SEDA endpoint, and one from the workqueue of the thread pool" (citate). What would you suggest?

Comment: Why do you need to share the pool? As the threads cannot be shared/reused anyway?

Comment: Consider I'm having 2 types of data to analyze - text data and binary data. Both are handled by different logic. Data analyzis is CPU-intensive task. Since I'm going to utilize CPU as much as possible I'd rather use shared thread pool with some numbers of threads calculated using availableProcessors() value. I need threads to be reused.

Answer (score 1):

from("direct:queue").threads(10)

it shares default thread pool